# Google Maps API Full Address Request

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the Google Maps API for my backend service written in Java.

I want to use a full address (1000 Generic Street, Generic Town, Texas) in the API; however, I am getting back null responses from the api call when using **1000+Generic+Street,+Generic+Town,+Texas** in the ORIGIN space. What am I doing wrong?

Even when I use **WACO,+TEXAS** I get null responses.

Here is the API call:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=ORIGIN&destination=DESTINATION&key=0000

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: You must not do anything wrong, when the directions-service returns no results it may  mean that either     origin or destination couldn't be resolved or no direction wasn't found. What is the value of the status-property of the response?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=1800%20Manor%20Road,%20Austin,%20TX%2078722&destination=6501%20Memorial%20Drive,%20Houston,%20TX%2077007

If you have a valid key use it otherwise just remove **&key=0000** until you get a valid key

[More Info here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/)